# Encode JWT properly

Tags: go, jwt

I'm trying to write simple JWT implementation with these functionalities:

- Generating token using `HMAC`
- Validating token (if signature is correct or exp is not timed out)
- Decode token and getting claims

from scratch for better understanding how does it work in depth.

So far I found this article [how to build an authentication microservice in golang from scratch](https://mattermost.com/blog/how-to-build-an-authentication-microservice-in-golang-from-scratch/). One chapter is dedicated to implementation JWT from scratch. I used it go generate token, however when I paste token in https://jwt.io I've got invalid signature and following warnings:

- **Warning**: Looks like your JWT signature is not encoded correctly using base64url (https://tools.ietforg/html/rfc4648#section-5). Note that padding ("=") must be omitted as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7515#section-2
- **Warning**: Looks like your JWT header is not encoded correctly using base64url (https://tools.ietforg/html/rfc4648#section-5). Note that padding ("=") must be omitted as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7515#section-2
- **Warning**: Looks like your JWT payload is not encoded correctly using base64url (https://tools.ietforg/html/rfc4648#section-5). Note that padding ("=") must be omitted as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7515#section-2

Token I paste look like below:
`eyAiYWxnIjogIkhTMjU2IiwgInR5cCI6ICJKV1QiIH0=.eyJhdWQiOiJmcm9udGVuZC5rbm93c2VhcmNoLm1sIiwiZXhwIjoiMTY1MTIyMjcyMyIsImlzcyI6Imtub3dzZWFyY2gubWwifQ==.SqCW8Hxakzck9Puzl0BEOkREPDyl38g2Fd4KFaDazV4=`

My JWT code implementation:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func GenerateToken(header string, payload map[string]string, secret string) (string, error) {
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(secret))
    header64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(header))

    payloadstr, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    payload64 := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(payloadstr)

    message := header64 + "." + payload64

    unsignedStr := header + string(payloadstr)

    h.Write([]byte(unsignedStr))
    signature := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))

    tokenStr := message + "." + signature
    return tokenStr, nil
}

func ValidateToken(token string, secret string) (bool, error) {
    splitToken := strings.Split(token, ".")

    if len(splitToken) != 3 {
        return false, nil
    }

    header, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(splitToken[0])
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    payload, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(splitToken[1])
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    unsignedStr := string(header) + string(payload)
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(secret))
    h.Write([]byte(unsignedStr))

    signature := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
    fmt.Println(signature)

    if signature != splitToken[2] {
        return false, nil
    }

    return true, nil
}

func main() {
    claimsMap := map[string]string{
        "aud": "frontend.knowsearch.ml",
        "iss": "knowsearch.ml",
        "exp": fmt.Sprint(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 2).Unix()),
    }
    secret := "Secure_Random_String"
    header := `{ "alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT" }`

    tokenString, err := GenerateToken(header, claimsMap, secret)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("token: ", tokenString)

    isValid, _ := ValidateToken(tokenString, secret)
    fmt.Println("is token valid: ", isValid)

    duration := time.Second * 4
    time.Sleep(duration)

    isValid, _ = ValidateToken(tokenString, secret)
    fmt.Println("is token valid: ", isValid)

}
```

### What's wrong with implementation above and how to fix it and get rid of warnings?

I decided to use `Golang` for implementation, however examples in any other languages very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JWT [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7515#section-2) requires that all padding `=` characters are removed:

> Base64 encoding using the URL- and filename-safe character set
> defined in Section 5 of RFC 4648 [RFC4648], with all trailing '='
> characters omitted (as permitted by Section 3.2) and without the
> inclusion of any line breaks, whitespace, or other additional
> characters.

You can use `base64.RawURLEncoding` , which creates Base64Url encoding without padding, instead of `base64.StdEncoding`.

You can see the differences between the `StdEncoding`, `RawStdEncoding`and `RawURLEncoding` in this short Go Playground [example](https://go.dev/play/p/xsUHkm6wGF8).

Also, I strongly recommend to use a [JWT library](https://jwt.io/libraries) if it's not for learning exercise.

Comment: here is an implementation in javascript that shows what is required to make the conversion https://thewoods.blog/base64url/

Comment: This can be useful as well:
https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose2go/blob/v1.5.0/base64url/base64url.go

Comment: @jps thanks, updated the answer and learned something new :)

Comment: @glad to help, hope you don't mind my little update of your answer to make the Base64 vs. Base64Url aspect a little bit clearer.